# Animation in HTML 5 is not working in android webview?

Tags: android, html, animation, webview

The problem in my application is after I scroll the whole page once then all animation in my HTML page in webview is properly working. So I want without scroll the page animation will work properly.

here is my code:

** Script**

```
function pageHeight()
{
    window.scroll(0,screen.height);
}
var cube = document.getElementById("cube");
var curRot=0;
var scrollStartPos=0;
var x=0;

if($LEAP.ipad){
    function onCubePress(e)
    {

        x = this.scrollTop+e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    function onCubeEnd(e)
    {
        if (Math.abs(x - e.changedTouches[0].pageX) > 10 ) {return;}
        x = 0;
        curRot-=90;
        cube.style.webkitTransform="rotateY("+curRot+"deg)";
        var modRot=(Math.abs(curRot/(90))%4)+1;
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    document.getElementById("hitarea").addEventListener('touchstart',onCubePress);
    document.getElementById("hitarea").addEventListener('touchend',onCubeEnd);
}
else {
    var myScroll;
    function loaded () {
        myScroll = new IScroll('#viewport', {
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: false,
            momentum: false,
            snap: true,
            snapSpeed: 200,
            keyBindings: true,
            indicators: {
                el: document.getElementById('indicator'),
                resize: false
            }
        });

        document.getElementById("indicator").addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            var val = Math.floor((e.pageX-459)/25);
            myScroll.scrollToElement(document.getElementById("graph"+(val+2)),400,null,true);
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    }
    window.onload = loaded;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, can you show us relevant code?

Comment: Here is my script code. I am adding some library file or javascript files like 'jquery.min.js','leap.js','IScroll.js'.

Comment: Please anybody suggest me